# Can you trigger an App via push notification to send a message/call automatically in IOS?

Tags: ios

I've read conflicting reports on this use case and find it difficult to come to a solid conclusion. I want my app to send a message/call upon receiving a push notification. I want to achieve this without any user interaction apart from push notifications. is this a possible use case in IOS?

ps - There's no limit to the number of push notifications that can be sent to trigger this functionality. An initial theory of mine was to use one to trigger the action and one to confirm it. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: If you mean a text message or a cellular call, no. User interaction is required to send a text or make a call. You can use a VoIP push to indicate an incoming VoIP call that would ring on the phone and which the user could answer

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I did mean text message/cellular call. I have seen scheduler apps claiming they can do it. Any ideas on how it's achieved?
https://www.businessinsider.com/schedule-text-message-iphone?r=US&IR=T

Comment: I understand that the user sets up the task, which means there is user interaction. But everything is done within the third-party app, isn't it possible to achieve the same thing from my app, replacing the user's touch interactions with push notifications?

Comment: No,  the user needs to send messages or make calls. You could send a notification. The user would then need to tap the notification to open your app. Your app could then present a dialog to make a call or send a message.  The user can cancel these if they want

Comment: can that user interaction come in the form of a voice command?

Comment: Not a voice command to your app. The user can say "hey Siri call X" or "hey Siri send a message to Y"